# Character class (e.g. '\\w') may not me used inside character range

Tags: java, android

I tried to use image URL regex inside my android app and i get the

`Character class (e.g. '\\w') may not me used inside character range` error.

My regex is

`"http(s?)://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ./]*)+\\.(?:[gG][iI][fF]|[jJ][pP][gG]|[jJ][pP][eE][gG]|[pP][nN][gG]|[bB][mM][pP])"`

The error is in `(/[\\w- ./]*)`

And the code

```
String pattern = "http(s?)://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ./]*)+\\.(?:[gG][iI][fF]|[jJ][pP][gG]|[jJ][pP][eE][gG]|[pP][nN][gG]|[bB][mM][pP])";
    Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher pageMatcher = linkPattern.matcher(data);
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: the character "-" in [] is used for range if not at the end so [\\w- ./] can't be evaluated as a range. Put "-" at the end

Comment: @JEY thank you. That helped.